# how do i get specific field in a form?

Tags: django

So what I'm trying to do is, I get long text from a user via the modelform I've created. Then in my models, I want to save the first sentence of the text. 
In order to do this, I believe I have to get the data(long text) from the form, and use a function to leave nothing but the first sentence. But I have as a beginner in Django, I have no idea on how to get an individual field from a form. So this is my codes:
models.py

```
class InputArticle(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'dansang', null=True, default=None)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contents = models.TextField(max_length=100000)
    first_sentence = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
class InputArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model=InputArticle
        fields=['title', 'contents']
```

I want to later display the title, contents, and first sentence in a separate page. 
I very much appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.contents = obj.contents.split('.')[0] # or whatever way you want to keep only first sentence
    obj.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call it individually with the field name, see [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

```
 {{ form.fieldname }}
```